# Oracle Stored Procedure Slow Performance

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures

i have a simple stored procedure. i use this to show data from my db. i want to optimize this query because i think this is slow. 31 seconds for 220.000 rows. so this is my query

```
BEGIN
    sql_base := 
            'SELECT
                p.id  
                ,p.cis  
                ,p.account_no  
                ,p.name  
                ,p.address   
                ,p.village_name   
                ,p.postal_code   
                ,p.subdistrict_name   
                ,p.regency_name   
                ,p.province_name   
                ,p.country_name   
                ,m.group_id   
                ,i.name   
                ,m.id   
                ,m.name   
                ,m.address   
                ,m.village_name   
                ,m.postal_code   
                ,m.subdistrict_name   
                ,m.regency_name   
                ,m.province_name   
                ,m.country_name  
                ,listagg (mMcc.name, '','') within group (order by mMcc.name) merchantMccName
                ,o.mid
                ,o.name
                ,o.mcc_id   outletMccId
                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(o.jenis_outlet,''ecomm'',''e-commerce''),''retail'',''toko'') jenisOutlet 
                ,o.MODIFIEDDATE
                ,o.CREATEDDATE
                ,o.CC_testing_ACCOUNTNO outletCcAccountNo
                ,o.DEBIT_testing_ACCNO outletDebitAccountNo
                ,MCC.name   outletMccName
                ,o.MCC_CODE   outletMccCode
                ,m.code   merchantCode
                ,p.jenisn abah   jenisn abah
                ,p.segmenn abah   segmenn abah
                ,p.IDENTITY_NO   identityNo
                ,p.IDENTITY_TYPE    identityType
                ,o.status   status
                ,NVL(o.ISOUTLET, 0)   isOutlet
                ,NVL(p.IS_ACCOUNT_testing, 0) isAccounttesting
                ,p.ACCOUNT_OTHERBANK_NO    accountOtherbankNo
                ,p.ACCOUNT_OTHERBANK_BANKNAME   accountOtherbankBankname
                ,p.ACCOUNT_OTHERBANK_NO    pemilikOtherBankAccountNo
                ,o.ADDRESS1   outletAddress1
                ,o.ADDRESS2   outletAddress2
                ,o.VILLAGE_NAME   outletVillageName
                ,o.POSTAL_CODE   outletPostalCode
                ,o.SUBDISTRICT_NAME   outletSubdistrictName
                ,o.REGENCY_NAME   outletRegencyName
                ,o.PROVINCE_NAME   outletProvinceName
                ,C E  WHEN NVL(o.IS_CC_TESTING,0)=1 THEN ''TESTING'' ELSE TO_CHAR(o.CC_OTHERBANK_NAME) END   outletCcBankName
                ,C E  WHEN NVL(o.IS_DEBIT_TESTING,0)=1 THEN ''TESTING'' ELSE TO_CHAR(o.CC_OTHERBANK_NAME) END   outletDebitBankName
                ,NVL(o.IS_CC_OTHERBANK,0) isCcOtherBank
                ,NVL(o.IS_CC_TESTING,0) is_cc_testing
                ,NVL(o.IS_DEBIT_testing,0) is_debit_testing
                ,o.CC_OTHERBANK_ACCNO ccOtherBankAccNo
                ,o.QRIS_STATIS_NMID nmid
                ,o.AGENT_BANK_CODE outletAgentBank
                
                FROM PEMILIK p
                LEFT JOIN  mytable m ON p.ID = m.PEM_ID
                LEFT JOIN  mytable2 i ON m.GROUP_ID = i.ID
                INNER JOIN  mytable3 o ON m.ID = o.MERCH_ID
                LEFT JOIN  mytable4 mMcc ON m.ID = mMcc.MERCH_ID
                LEFT JOIN  mytable5 mcc ON MCC.ID = o.MCC_ID 
                
           GROUP BY 
               *SAME LIKE SELECT*;
                
    final_result:='SELECT rec.*, count (*) over ()CountData FROM ('        
            || sql_base || ') rec  '
            ||WHERE_Q
            ||ORDERBY_Q||' '||PAGING_Q ;
            
    OPEN O_RESULT_REC FOR 
        final_result;
```

i already tried to change the query but still i think my query still not good. any tips to improve my query? should i change the connection in java? or this is just query problem?

Comment: If you want help optimizing a query, you're going to need to provide things like the query plan, table definitions, index definitions, etc.  What is 31 seconds a measure of?  The time required to fetch all 220,000 rows to a client machine?  If so, how much of that is time spent in the database vs. time fetching data over the network?

Comment: @JustinCave my query is to show selected data and show it in json format. i test it in postman, it needs 30 seconds to query it. i use paging too.

Comment: OK.  So 31 seconds includes an unknown amount of time at the app server level fetching data, bundling it into JSON, and sending that data over the network to the client.  So we have no idea if the performance problem is in the database, the app server, the network, etc.